# gesturesEnabled: false doesn't work in React Native

Tags: react-native

**I'm using**

```js
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.8",
```

**code**

```js
const RankingStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Ranking,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Ranking',
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'ranking',
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
  },
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  RankingStack,
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
});
```

I don't know why this `gesturesEnabled: false` doesn't work.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `gestureEnabled:false` ? without **"s"**

**Update**  after @LPFJ tried, it worked like this:

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  RankingStack,
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gestureEnabled: false
  }
});
```

[DOC](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/#gestureenabled)

Comment: Thank you as always.  But ```gestureEnabled: false``` doesn't work. I wanna avoid swiping back at Ranking. To avoid it, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you could try [these](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1063#issuecomment-586932461)

Comment: Thank you so much! I love you!

Answer (score 1):

My packages versions:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.6.2",
```

In order to disable the back gesture you need to do a tricky thing.
You need to add

> gestureEnabled: false

To both Navigator and Screen

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}/>
  <Stack.Screen 
    options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
    component={YourScreenWithoutGesture}
  />
  <Stack.Screen 
    component={YourScreenWithGesture}
  />
<Stack.Navigator />
```

It seems to me that this should be changed because it is very counterintuitive and misleading...

Answer (score 0):

shout out to @高鵬翔

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  RankingStack,
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Loading',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    gestureEnabled: false
  }
});
```

This Worked!